# Rails: Can't access questions associated with answers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error
    undefined method `question_answers_path'
for this line of code @question.answers

I have answers belong_to question, questions has_many answers, and I have added a migration to answers 
    rails g migration add_question_id_to_answers question_id: integer

I've just ran the db:migrate, but can't figure out why the method is undefined.

CODE

I render <%= @question.answers % and in the answer file I do

<%= answer.answer %>

My answer migration add_question_id looks like this

```
class AddQuestionIdToAnswer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :answers, :question_id, :integer
    add_index :answers, :question_id
  end
end
```

My question looks like this

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  attr_accessible :query, :text
  validates :query, presence: true
end
```

My answer looks like this

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :question
  attr_accessible :anonymous, :answer, :commenter, :votes
end
```

Comment: Please paste the necessary code. What you describe should work, so the issue is most likely something overlooked in the code.

Comment: I've added the code for my answers/questions model, my database migration file, and the short snippets where the error appears, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined the route in `config/routes.rb` ? Specifically, have you nested answers inside questions?

Something like:

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers
end
```

You might also try something like `rake routes | grep answers` from the command line to see if the route exists.

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Ah, I think this might be it, I'll try it out. And side note, is it good practice to have nested resources within resources? Such as comments in answers, and then answers in questions?

Comment: @google1254 I will refer you to the Rails Guides: "Deeply-nested resources quickly become cumbersome...Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep." Look specifically at section 2.7.2 in the link above and try using `shallow: true`

Comment: Thanks! Wondering if I have comments belonging to answers and answers belonging to questions, if I have both comments&answers nested as shallow resources, the paths would work?